# preg_replace to wrap an image that is a link, with a li

Tags: php, preg-replace

Sorry for the slightly confusing title, but I'm trying to wrap `<li></li>` tags around an image which is a link (so `<a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>`) using preg replace, I've tried the following code:

```
preg_replace('/(<a [^>]+>)/','<li>\1</li>',$myVar );
```

but this has an odd outcome - can anybody point me in the right direction? I know it can be done with jQuery but I'd much rather a PHP solution.

Comment: Repeat after me. HTML cannot be parsed using regex. HTML cannot be parsed using regex. HTML cannot be parsed using regex. Use a DOM parser/manipulator instead. In any case, your replace will generate invalid HTML since it is wrapping <li> around the opening <a> tag, so <a><li></a>, which is invalid.

Comment: So I've just got the desired affect using string replace to replace any <a href with <li><a href and any </a> with </a></li> it's for a very specific situation where the url's would always be in that pattern, and I would always want an li around a link - is this a particularly bad thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that you should **never** parse an html string using regular expressions like [@slugonamission](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235700/slugonamission) wrote in the comments, here:

```
$str = preg_replace('~<a .*?>\s*<img .*?>\s*</a>~i','<li>$0</li>',$str);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do it:

```
preg_replace('/<a(.*)>(.*)<\\/a>/','<li><a$1>$2</a></li>',$myVar );
```